# Dynamically loaded slider

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery

**Problem**: Make a slider, located at the bottom of the page. The slider should be dynamically loaded only when a div (`#slider`) becomes visible on the screen. Images do not have to load all at once. Load the first two images, then load the third when we switched to the second, and so on.

I would like other users to look look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong and what could be done better (if you can - in more detail).

```js
$(function () {
    var countImg = 5,
        indexImg = 1,
        indexImgLoad = 2,
        pathImg = '/img/slider/',
        formatImg = 'jpg',
        controlFlag = 1,
        elWrap = $('#slider'),
        el =  elWrap.find('img');
    function create () {
        Img = new Image(); 
        Img.src= pathImg+indexImg+'.'+formatImg;                        
        $(Img).appendTo($("#slides"));
        $('<span class="next"></span><span class="prev"></span>').appendTo($("#slider"));
        navigation();
        check();
    }
    function change () {
        el.fadeOut(500);
        el.filter(':nth-child('+indexImg+')').fadeIn(500);
    }
    function newimg() {
        nextImg = new Image(); 
        nextImg.src= pathImg+indexImgLoad+'.'+formatImg;                        
        $(nextImg).appendTo($("#slides"));
    }
    function check() {
        if (controlFlag && indexImgLoad <= countImg) {
            newimg();        
        }
        if (controlFlag){
            el =  elWrap.find('img');
        }
        if (el.length == countImg){    
            controlFlag = 0;
        }
    }
    function navigation(){
        $('span.next').click(function() {
            indexImg++;
            indexImgLoad++;
            if(indexImg > countImg) {
                indexImg = 1;
            }
            check();
            change();
        });
        $('span.prev').click(function() {
            indexImg--;                    
            if(indexImg < 1) {
                indexImg = countImg;
            }
            indexImgLoad++;
            check();
            change ();
        });    
    }
    var loadSlider = 1;
    window.onscroll = function() {                
          var pageY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        heightScreen = window.innerHeight + pageY;
        sliderTopY = $("#slides").offset().top;
        if ((heightScreen > (sliderTopY - sliderTopY * 0.05)) && loadSlider) {
            loadSlider = 0;
            create();
        } 
    }
});
```

```css
.slider_wrap {
        margin: 0px auto 0;
        width: 735px;
        height: 200px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .slider_wrap img {
        width: 645px;
        height: auto;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 45px;    
    }
    .slider_wrap img:first-child {
        display: block;
    }
    .slider_wrap span {
        width: 45px;
        height: 200px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: url(/img/rotator_buttons.png) no-repeat;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    .slider_wrap span.next {
        right: 0;
        background-position: -45px 0;
    }
    .slider_wrap span.next:hover, span.prev:hover {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    .slider_wrap span.prev {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:1800px;">div: height = 1800px</div>
    <div id="slider" class="slider_wrap">
        <div id="slides">
        </div>            
    </div>
```

Comment: (quote)The slider should be dynamically loaded only when an `unicorn` becomes visible on the screen.(/quote)

Comment: Sorry :) There was: div id=slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

1. You can create a plugin out of it (create divs `#slider` and `#slides` - don't use id, but just reference - and add class slider_wrap in code)
2. You don't put var before `nextImg = new Image();`
3. Instead of new Image you can use jQuery:

   `$('<img/>').attr('src', path).appendTo($("#slides"));`
4. Instead of `$('span.next')` use `elWrap.find('span.next')` because it will not work if span.next is somewhere in the html.
5. Is always better ot use jQuery not native function because they may be different from browser to browser. So use `$(window).scroll(function() { })` `$(window).innerHeight()` and `$(window).scrollTop();`
6. Inside newimg you call `$("#slides")` you can call that before a function and store it's value in variable.